# Classic ASP Mixed Vbscript Jscript - How to Automate Execution

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, jscript

I need to automate a script that is mostly VBScript, but has some JScript in it to test JSON objects as well as a JSON parser that is also written in Jscript.  Also, we have a bunch of INCLUDE files (I could do an ExecuteGlobal on them, but there are a bunch of hurdles there too).  Normally I would just take all my Classic ASP code, make adjustments for VBS files, save, and set up a task on the server to execute.  The issue is the mixed JScript.

Is there a way to execute a classic ASP file automatically that I am not aware of? I could redirect the first visitor of the day or something to a page and then once the page is done, redirect them to the requested page, but that's really a hack.  But, maybe a hack is the only way to do this.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Dennis

Comment: Why did someone vote this down??

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the best way to do this is with a XML HTTP get request on the page from a VBS file that I set up as a scheduled task.

```
Set objXML = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
objXML.open "GET", "Full-URL-HERE", false
objXML.send()
sResponse = objXML.responseText
Set objXML = Nothing
```

Then Full-URL-HERE is the URL to the page that you wanted to automate.